# refining a simple code in R, it all works I want to polish it

Tags: r

here is my data
https://filebin.net/i2wpmeb19dacs3nr
it's very simple calculation to do but my code is messy.

```
#plot
library(ggplot2)
library(Hmisc)
library(svglite)
# Basic dot plot

#to use summary stat NA rows has to be delleted (or otherwise ignored)
leaf_count_jas_comlete<-leaf_count_jas[complete.cases(leaf_count_jas), ]

#all factors to character
leaf_count_jas_comlete <- data.frame(lapply(leaf_count_jas_comlete, as.character),      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#change class for numbers
leaf_count_jas_comlete$leaf.no.<- as.numeric(leaf_count_jas_comlete$leaf.no.)
leaf_count_jas_comlete$height..cm.<- as.numeric(leaf_count_jas_comlete$height..cm.)

svg("rplot_height..cm..svg")
ggplot(leaf_count_jas_comlete, aes(x=genotype, y=height..cm.)) + 
geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', binwidth = 1, dotsize = 0.3)+

stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=18,
           size=3, color="blue") +

stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl, fun.args = list(mult=1), 
           geom="pointrange", color="blue")

dev.off() 

#calculate mean and sd per group and export to a new table
library(plyr)

##add NA count
dt <- leaf_count_jas_comlete
jas_summary<-data.frame()
jas_summary_h<-ddply(dt,~genotype,summarise,mean=mean(height..cm.),sd=sd(height..cm.))
jas_summary_l<-ddply(dt,~genotype,summarise,mean=mean(leaf.no.),sd=sd(leaf.no.))
jas_summary_h_l<-merge(jas_summary_h,jas_summary_l, by="genotype", all=TRUE)
library(plyr)
n<-count(leaf_count_jas, "genotype")
dead<-aggregate(leaf.no. ~ genotype, leaf_count_jas, function(x) {sum(is.na(x))}, na.action = NULL)

jas_summary_h_l_dead<-merge(jas_summary_h_l,dead, by="genotype", all=TRUE)
jas_summary_h_l_dead_n<-merge(jas_summary_h_l_dead,n, by="genotype", all=TRUE)
```

I would like to start coding in simpler way. For example how to make an empty df
and fill it with the summary data so it has a column called "genotype", "mean_leaf_no", "leaf_no_sd", "mean_height", "height_sd", "no_plants" and "dead_plants" and gradually fill it with the calculations instead of merging new dfs? also now when I have it as it is I need to name the columns, but I would like this piece of code to be usable for many times so I would like the name to be constructed based on the original dfs col names (genotype, leaf_no, height) so for example if someone will measure "flowers_no" so it can keep the correct name all over to the summary table.
Help, please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using the tidyverse if you'd like more simple code.

For example, the first part would be:

```
library(tidyverse); library(magrittr); library(janitor)

new_set = leaf_count_jas_comlete %>% 
# clean names
clean_names() %>%
# remove rows with NA
drop_na() %>% 
# convert factors to character
mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
#convert to numeric
mutate(leaf_no=as.numeric(leaf_no), height_cm=as.numeric(height_cm))

new_set %>% 
group_by(genotype) %>% 
summarize(mean_height=mean(height_cm), sd_height=sd(height_cm))
```

Comment: ok, thanks. This looks simpler, and what about "building" a summary table? Could you help with that?

Comment: aaaah so mutate I will use more often, looks like it can apply

Comment: whenever you want to summarize something, you can use the group_by() %>% summarize() function in tidyverse.

Comment: sorry but I am not getting it ##add NA count
dt <- leaf_count_jas_comlete
jas_summary<-data.frame()
jas_summary_h<-ddply(dt,~genotype,summarise,mean=mean(height..cm.),sd=sd(height..cm.))
jas_summ ....), I want to know that for general use not only for this example. if the result is several columns I want to do similar to this but multiple columns aa <- within(aa, z <- x + y - 2)

Comment: added group_by/summarize